# Элегантный пересчет координат с учётом разрешения отображаемого обьекта

Tags: c++, c, математика

Вопрос скорее про математику, но хочется 'элегантного' решения.

Речь идёт о изображениях, имеем:

- размер исходного изображения 1200х800
- размер масштабированого изображения 967х534
- точка координат на масштабированом изображении 127х238

Как красиво привести координаты второго изображения к тем же координатам оригинального изображения?

На ум приходит нечто ужасное типа:

```
int originWidth = 1200;
int viewWidth = 967;
double dow = originWidth / 100;
double dvw = viewWidth / 100;
double dvpointWidth = (127 / dvw) * dow;
// ... итд в том же духе
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91630/discussion-on-question-by-newview------).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
int originWidth = 1200;
int viewWidth = 967;
int pointWidth = 127;
double dvpointWidth = (pointWidth / double(viewWidth)) * originWidth;
```

Comment: Андрейка, зачем вы скопировали мой никчёмный пошаговый пример? :)

Comment: Я не делю координаты на `100`, эта константа сокращается. Более элегантно поделить и умножить числа в C++ нельзя :)

Comment: @freim в таком случае, проверьте формулировку вопроса. Нельзя посчитать формулу `a / b * c` более кратко и элегантно чем в коде в моем ответе :)

Comment: Вообще-то можно. В частности там можно обойтись целочисленной арифметикой.